# Exactness of $\varprojlim$ on short exact sequence of Mittag-Leffler systems

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $I$ be a directed set. A prjective system $\{V_i, f_{ij}\}$ of abelian groups is called Mittag-Leffler if for each $i\in I$, the family $f_{ij}(V_j)\subseteq V_i$ for j≥i stabilizes.

Let $0\to \{U_i\}\to \{V_i\}\to \{W_i\}\to 0$ be an exact sequence of projective systems over $I$. In stacks project https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0598, it is essentially shown that if $I$ has a  countable cofinal subset and $\{U_i\}$ is Mittag-Leffler then the following  sequence
$$
0\to \varprojlim U_i \to \varprojlim V_i \to \varprojlim W_i \to 0
$$
is exact.

My question is that is it true for arbitrary direct set $I$?

Thanks a lot!

PS: In P. Gabriel's thesis "Des Categories Abeliennes", it is claimed that this is true for arbitrary $I$ (See Lemma 1 in page 391 of loc. cit.), provided that $U_i$ are all artinian. The proof can be found in Page 202 of  Bourbaki's "Theory of sets".

Comment: There is a long exact sequence $0\to \varprojlim U_i \to \varprojlim V_i \to \varprojlim W_i \to  \varprojlim^{1} U_i \to \varprojlim^{1} V_i \to \varprojlim^{2} U_i  \to \varprojlim^{2} U_i \to \ldots$. Thus your sequence is exact if $\varprojlim^{1} U_i  0 =0$. There are a lot of vanishing theorems for the first derived limit, perhaps you can find something useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a counterexample if and only if $I$ has uncountable cofinality. I suspect this is well-known, but I couldn't find it explicitly stated in the literature, although related facts can be found.

It's closely related to the fact that $I$ has uncountable cofinality if and only if there is a "surjective" inverse system $\mathcal{X}=\{X_i,f_{ij}\}$ of nonempty sets on $I$ (i.e., one with all $f_{ij}$ surjective) that has an empty inverse limit.

This is proved in

*Henkin, Leon*, [**A problem on inverse mapping systems**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2031926), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 1, 224-225 (1950). [ZBL0041.52204](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0041.52204).

with a slightly simplified proof in [this unpublished note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/papers/unpub/emptylim.pdf) of George Bergman, which also contains lots of other interesting related material.

If you just want one example of such an inverse system, there is a very simple one in

*Waterhouse, William C.*, [**An empty inverse limit**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2039210), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 36(1972), 618 (1973). [ZBL0259.54008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0259.54008).

[They don't write papers like that any more! Excluding title and references, it is six lines long. And it doesn't skimp on an introduction: the first two lines describe what is going to happen in the last four lines.]

Once you have such an inverse system $\mathcal{X}$, it has a surjective map to the constant inverse system $\mathcal{C}=\{C_i,g_{ij}\}$ with $C_i$ a singleton for every $i\in I$.

Now linearize: for $k$ a commutative ring form the inverse system $k\mathcal{X}=\{kX_i,\hat{f}_{ij}\}$ where $kX_i$ is the free $k$-module with basis $X_i$ and the $\hat{f}_{ij}$ are obtained by linearly extending the $f_{ij}$.

It's not too hard to check that $k\mathcal{X}$ is a surjective inverse system of $k$-modules whose inverse limit is $0$. You can find the argument in

*Higman, Graham; Stone, A. H.*, [**On inverse systems with trivial limits**](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-29.2.233), J. Lond. Math. Soc. 29, 233-236 (1954). [ZBL0055.02503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0055.02503).

But now we have a surjective map $k\mathcal{X}\to k\mathcal{C}$ that can't induce a surjective map on inverse limits, since $\varprojlim k\mathcal{X}\cong0$ but $\varprojlim k\mathcal{X}\cong k$. And the kernel of  $k\mathcal{X}\to k\mathcal{C}$ is also a surjective (and hence Mittag-Leffler) inverse system.

Comment: A great answer. Thanks a lot!